# Original Image FileName in Caffe Network

Tags: image, classification, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am using Cifar(https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/examples/cifar10) like model in caffe. I am able to train the model and get the probability of wrongly classified images using pycaffe interface.

Is it possible to get the name of the image filename from data layer (created lmdb from list of image filename and label with train.txt and val.txt - https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/imagenet/create_imagenet.sh)?

If not, how do you check the content (original image's filename written in train.txt) of wrongly classified image (not only labels)?

Comment: if you don't `--shuffle` in `create_imageset` then you might be able to recover the original image.